# Could NOT find Freetype (missing: FREETYPE_LIBRARY) on Cmake

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I am trying build the [Chlumsky msdfgen](https://github.com/Chlumsky/msdfgen) library on Windows and I'm using Cmake GUI. No matter what I do I can't get Cmake to configure properly. This library has Freetype as a dependency, and I set the include directories for Freetype, but I constantly get a message that it was not able to find Freetype. How does it know where to look for the Freetype libraries?

> CMake Error at C:/Program
> Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230
> (message):   Could NOT find Freetype (missing: FREETYPE_LIBRARY)
> (found version   "2.12.1")

Answer (score 0):

You need to use vcpkg with cmake and it will work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).